# Create automatic new row with flex direction column, using fixed height of the div

Tags: html, css

I am using flex of type column to show the list of content. How to make automatically new row of content without changing the div height? Must be filled right part of the div.

Overflow to a new row does not work.
Flex direction row working, but I don`t need it.

```css
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.container ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Number one</li>
    <li>Number two</li>
    <li>Number three</li>
    <li>Number four</li>
    <li>Number five</li>
    <li>Number six</li>
    <li>Number seven</li>
    <li>Number eight</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: in addition to the answers below I would probably consider `max-height:100%` instead

Answer (score 3):

For the list you need to inherit the height, or set it to 100% of its parent

```css
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.container ul{  
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Number one</li>
    <li>Number two</li>
    <li>Number three</li>
    <li>Number four</li>
    <li>Number five</li>
    <li>Number six</li>
    <li>Number seven</li>
    <li>Number eight</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add just `height:100%;` to `ul`

```css
.container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
.container ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Number one</li>
    <li>Number two</li>
    <li>Number three</li>
    <li>Number four</li>
    <li>Number five</li>
    <li>Number six</li>
    <li>Number seven</li>
    <li>Number eight</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```